# Path as parameter in route path

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I need to follow a spec that requires a GET using a "path" in route path.

Scenario #1: https://example.com/param1/param2/file.txt

Scenario #2: https://example.com/param1/param2/folder/file.txt

Initially I tried with the very standard implementation:

```
app.get('/:param1/:param2/:path', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

It works as expected for first scenario.
However for second one I receive a 404 as express router looks for the complete path, that of course.. does not exist.

I know, passing the path as url parameter would easily solve this problem.
But requirements are to use the path... as path.

How can I trick express router to get the rest of the path as my last parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: why there is no route name? directly you will be sending params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a [regex pattern to match](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) the remaining part of the route.

```
const express = require('express');

app = express();

app.get('/:param1/:param2/:path([\\w\\W]+)', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params)
  })
  
  
app.listen(9000);
```

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9000/foo/bar/bat
{"param1":"foo","param2":"bar","path":"bat"}
```

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9000/foo/bar/bat/def.dex

{"param1":"foo","param2":"bar","path":"bat/def.dex"}
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` sign after your desired route, something like this:

```js
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params[0]); 
});

// GET /:param1/:param2/...
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. But is there a way to assign a parameter name for the wildcard?

Comment: You could mention any parameter before the ```*``` sign, something like ```/:param1/:param2/*```. Anything after these parameters will be considered a whole path string.